# Sync only the latest change list number files using P4V

Tags: perforce

Is there any way to sync only the latest change list number changes.

For example if the latest change number is 1234 and has 2 files in submitted changelist. I want to sync only those 2 files not the complete folder.

The below command is syncing only the 2 files

`p4 sync -f //demo/osb/Test/...@=1234;`

I want to pass this value dynamically as this value will change.

I have tried the below commands but none are working.

`p4 sync -f //demo/osb/Test/...@head;`

`p4 sync -f //demo/osb/Test/...@=head;`

`p4 sync -f //demo/osb/Test/...#head;` --> this is updating the complete folder

`p4 sync -f //demo/osb/Test/...#=head;` --> this is updating the complete folder

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use two commands:

```
p4 -F %change% -ztag changes -m1 -s submitted //demo/osb/Test/...

p4 sync //demo/osb/Test/...@=NNN
```

The first command tells you the change number of the latest submitted change. The second command syncs the files changed in that changelist.

Depending on your shell, you could perhaps combine them:

```
p4 sync //demo/osb/Test/...@=`p4 -F %change% -ztag changes -m1 -s submitted //demo/osb/Test/...`
```

(Whew! That's a mouthful!)

You have to have a fairly recent client version for the '-F %change%' syntax to work; if you're having trouble with this part of the solution, check your client version.